# SwiftChart Library not working with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swiftcharts

I have used [SwiftChart](https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart?ref=ioscookies.com) to implement Line and area chart like below image [image: Line and chart area].

It works fine with Xcode 7.3. Now am porting my code to iOS 10 so converting the code to Swift 3.0. I'm getting following error:

U

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues[0]), zero)

for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues[i]), CGFloat(yValues[i]))
}

CGPathAddLineToPoint(area, nil, CGFloat(xValues.last!), zero)
```

and

```
if labels[i] != 0 {
    // Horizontal grid for 0 is not dashed\
    CGContextSetLineDash(context,phase:0,lengths:[5],count:1)
   // CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, [5], 1)
} else {
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, nil, 0)
}
```

Please help me in fixing this issue

Comment: SwiftChart has been updated this month to the latest Swift / Xcode – do you still have this problem?

Comment: Will check and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update of [SwiftChart](https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart?ref=ioscookies.com) fixes the issue mentioned above . please update your swift chart lib code to latest